# R dynamic time warping for long time series

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate the dtw distance for very long time series but I get an error that shows I cannot allocate memory for the matrix.

Here what I do:

```
library(dtw)

set.seed(1234)
N <- 300000
x <- rnorm(N)
y <- rnorm(N)

dtw(x,y,distance.only=TRUE)$distance

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 670.6 Gb
```

Is there an alternative way to calculate the dtw distance that does not need to allocate so much memory?

Answer (score 1):

Idon't know this package , but From the [companion paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v31/i07/) of the package you have:

> Larger problems may be addressed by approximate strategies, e.g.,
>   computing a preliminary alignment between downsampled time series
>   (Salvador and Chan 2004); indexing (Keogh and Ratanamahatana 2005); or
>   breaking one of the sequences into chunks and then iterating
>   subsequence matches.

The latter option  can be implemented by something like :

```
  lapply(split(y,1:100),                      ## I split y in 100 chnucks
       function(z)dtw(x,z,distance.only=TRUE)$distance)
```

PS: By larger here , it means problems that exceed 8000 × 8000 points (close to the virtual memory limit) which it is your case here.

Comment: thanks, but this does not work. Even splitting y in 1000 chucks I still get a similar error: "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 686.6 Mb".

Comment: @Lilith hum...maybe you should move to approximate strategies( and with  some luck you should find an R package that implement them).

Comment: @Lilith [this ressource](http://nipunbatra.github.io/2014/07/dtw/) in python looks very interseting